# Does every type have a corresponding literal?

Tags: c++, oop

According to Bjarne Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ (Sixth Printing, November 2012)*, **"each of [the] types [`int`, `double`, `char`, `string`, and `bool`] has its own characteristic style of literals"** (p.63).

In §A.2 of the same book, additional varieties of `int` (unsigned; long) and floating-point-literals are mentioned, as well as the (null) pointer literal.

**Does *every* type have a corresponding literal?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bjarne Stroustrup's *Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ (Sixth Printing, November 2012)* refers to [ISO/IEC 14882:2003](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall11/CSCI-GA.2110-003/documents/c++2003std.pdf) as the relevant C++ standard. In this can be found the pertinent section, §2.13, which reads as follows:

```
2.13 Literals

There are several kinds of literals.

literal:
    integer-literal
    character-literal
    floating-literal
    string-literal
    boolean-literal
```

Apparently, this is an exhaustive list; and because there can be many more types than there are kinds of literal in that list, the answer is: **no, not every type has a corresponding literal.**

*N.B. for the C++11 case, please see [Lizusek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22199042/82216).*

Answer (score 5):

> C++ Standard n3337  **§** 2.14.1/1:
>
> There are several kinds of literals.
>
> literal:
>
> integer-literal
>
> character-literal
>
> floating-literal
>
> string-literal
>
> boolean-literal
>
> pointer-literal
>
> user-defined-literal

No, not avery type has a literal. Classes do not have literal, as well as i.e `void`, `int*`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`.

---

### Literals explained:

**integer-literal**

An integer literal is a sequence of digits that has no period or exponent part.

example:  `1`

**character-literal**

A character literal is one or more characters enclosed in single quotes, as in ’x’, optionally preceded by
one of the letters u, U, or L, as in u’y’, U’z’, or L’x’, respectively.

’ c-char-sequence ’

u’ c-char-sequence ’

U’ c-char-sequence ’

L’ c-char-sequence ’

example:  `'a'`, `'ab'`, `'\''`, `L'0'`, `'('`

**floating-literal**

A floating literal consists of an integer part, a decimal point, a fraction part, an e or E, an optionally signed
integer exponent, and an optional type suffix. The integer and fraction parts both consist of a sequence of
decimal (base ten) digits. Either the integer part or the fraction part (not both) can be omitted; either the
decimal point or the letter e (or E ) and the exponent (not both) can be omitted. The integer part, the
optional decimal point and the optional fraction part form the significant part of the floating literal. The
exponent, if present, indicates the power of 10 by which the significant part is to be scaled.

example: `123.456e-67`, `.1E1f`, `42.`, 1`3e3`

**string-literal**

A string literal is a sequence of characters (as defined in 2.14.3) surrounded by double quotes, optionally
prefixed by R, u8, u8R, u, uR, U, UR, L, or LR, as in "...", R"(...)", u8"...", u8R"**(...)**", u"...",
uR"* ̃(...)* ̃", U"...", UR"zzz(...)zzz", L"...", or LR"(...)", respectively.

encoding-prefixopt " s-char-sequenceopt "

encoding-prefixopt R raw-string

example: `"me"`, `L"you"`

**boolean-literal**

The Boolean literals are the keywords `false` and `true`. Such literals are `prvalues` and have type `bool`.

```
false
true
```

**pointer-literal**

The pointer literal is the keyword `nullptr`. It is a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t`.

```
nullptr
```

**user-defined-literal**

Overload of `operator""` that allows to interpret literal using user-defined logic.

example:

```
typedef double signalf;
constexpr signalf operator"" _percent( long double val) { return val / 100 ; }

std::cout  << 12.34_percent; // prints 0.1234
```

Comment: example of a pointer-literal?

Comment: @Yakk: `nullptr` is the only one.

Answer (score 1):

There's no literal for `int*`. The closest you get is `nullptr`, but its type is `nullptr_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Most types do not have a literal. Classes do not have one. Pointers, references, r-value references have none, as well. `void` does not have a literal.

You mentioned `string` which also does not have a literal, it only has a constructor that takes a `const char*` literal! C++ calls this constructor implicitly, when assigning a `const char*` literal to a string.

Comment: I think he might be referring to `"foo"s`.

Comment: @faranwath: Okay, but this is C++11 and is a user defined literal, i.e., a function call to the `operator""` function which I would not count as a true literal.

Comment: The fact that a feature belongs to the 2011 standard does not make it unsuitable for being considered as an answer. And yes, this isn't a _true_ literal, but it looks like one, so it kinda is.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the list, there's no literals for `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, `unsigned short`.

You should probably think in terms of the limited list of types for which there are literals, rather than the types for which there are not. Literals are for:

- bool
- char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t
- "array of const" char, wchar_t, char16_t, char32_t (that is, string literals)
- int, unsigned int
- long, unsigned long
- long long, unsigned long long
- float, double, long double
- std::nullptr_t

plus user-defined literals.

Comment: An interesting question: could an enumeration constant be considered a literal?  It has some of the characteristics (but not all).  (It's not considered a literal by the standard, but I suspect that's simply because there is no special lexical construct to support it.  It's just a symbol at the lexical level.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: maybe. I don't know of any really good formal definition of a literal. I work with "a production that the grammar calls a literal, and that you'd sort of expect represents a value known at compile time". If an enum value is a literal, then is a `static const int` variable a literal? I'd distinguish the enum from the `int` by saying that in C++ literals don't represent objects, just values, except that string literals do represent objects.

Comment: And enumeration constants don't:-).  I'd generally just follow the language definition; if the language definition calls it a literal, it's a literal.  On the other hand, this would include user defined literals, and exclude enumeration constants, which doesn't seem too natural either.  Whence the question.  I don't think that there's an absolute answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all type `std::string` has no its own literals.
Only arithmetic types have their own literals. The exception is string literals that has type of `const char arrays` and not so fer introduced in the C++ 11 `nullptr` of type `std::nullptr_t`

Take into account that `bool` is an arithmetic type.

Comment: Not all arithmetic types have literals.