# Depreciated conversion from string constant to 'char*'

Tags: c++, c, string, compiler-construction, char

I hope someone can help me. I'm converting a C language program to C++ in order to easily use strings but when I go to compile, I get this error:

```
inventory.cpp:225: warning: depreciated conversion from string constant to 'char*'
```

**This is where the code in question:**

```
#define FNAME "database.dat"


// test data struct
struct t_Record
{
    int number;
    char word[100];
    //String word[];
} Record;

int main (void)
{
    int Rec = 0; // record number
    FILE *File;

    srand(time(NULL));

    File = FileOpen(FNAME); 
    if (!File)
    {
          printf("Error hommie!\n\n");
          exit(-1);
    }

    ...etc.
```

**This is where the compiler tells me the error occurred:**

```
File = FileOpen(FNAME);
```

I just don't see what is wrong...

The place where the compiler tell me to look doesn't even have a string or char associated with it??

Now I understand this error has been seen before, but my question is specific to my code.

Comment: You need to look at the function prototype for the `FileOpen` function. What type of argument does it expect?

Comment: If `FileOpen` expects `char*` without intent on modifying the passed character data, thump the author upside the noggin, because that parameter should be `char const*`.

Comment: Never knew the compiler to depreciate anything before...

Comment: @Deduplicator:  The compiler didn't; the language standard did.

Comment: @Clifford: That was ironic. And I'm quite sure the standard deprecates, not not depreciates.

Comment: @Deduplicator:  Your dry wit is not really coming across in text - perhaps a wink was in order? ;-)

Comment: That looks like a g++ error message -- except that the actual message uses the word "deprecated", not "depreciated". It appears that you've re-typed the error message rather than copy-and-pasting it. Please copy-and-paste the *exact* error message. Subtle nuances like this can be very significant (though this one probably isn't).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to convert a [*string literal*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22199042/1141471) (with type `const char[]`) to `char*`.

> The place where the compiler tell me to look doesn't even have a
>   string or char associated with it??

Yes, it is on the top of the file:

```
#define FNAME "database.dat"
```

**C++ Standard n3337  § 2.14.5/1**

String literals

> A string literal is a sequence of characters (as defined in 2.14.3)
>   surrounded by double quotes, optionally prefixed by R, u8, u8R, u, uR,
>   U, UR, L, or LR, as in "...", R"(...)", u8"...", u8R"(...)", u"...",
>   uR"* ̃(...)* ̃", U"...", UR"zzz(...)zzz", L"...", or LR"(...)",
>   respectively.

You can avoid the warning by casting to `char*`:

```
File = FileOpen( (char*)FNAME);
```

Even better modify `FileOpen` to accept a `const char*`. This will be more safe and just right as you don't intend to modify the string.

Comment: Better yet, modify `FileOpen` to accept a `const char*` like a good citizen.

Comment: using you're modification I'm getting a lot of other errors with my other mthods. I'm going to attempt to debug when I get home...will update you guys, thanks.

Comment: *functions not methods

Comment: @mosawi just change signature of FileOpen to take const char* instead of char*, other errors are not related to FileOpen

Comment: yea I did do that, but I'm getting errors with other functions because of dependencies. I guess I should post all the code so you guys can see what I'm taking about

Comment: I'm soo stupid, i included <string> in c++ and not <cstring>...program at least works now!

Answer (score 0):

As @lizusek said, you can avoid the warning by type casting to `char*`, but even better would be to rewrite your code to avoid type casting. While it can work and solve a lot of headaches, it can be very dangerous if you type cast the wrong things.